# Red hat enterprise 5 Linux with Python 2.5

Tags: python, linux, django

I have to deploy a Django project on Red hat enterprise linux 5, the project has been developed on Python 2.5 but the server environment has Python 2.4 which is causing some issues. I googled a lot over internet to get the Python 2.5 built rpm for the server but there are only src rpm available for the mentioned Linux version.

I have not been allowed to compile and use the src rpm due to some system administration issues.

Is there any Linux version which is easily available and has python 2.5 as default? or any link to the python 2.5 built rpm.

Please suggest.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend [ActivePython](http://www.activestate.com/activepython), it's pretty brain dead easy to install and it works pretty well with redhat in my experience.

Answer (score 1):

Install the python package from http://iuscommunity.org/

Answer (score 0):

This would help you with finding a linux distro with specifications
 [DistroWatch](http://distrowatch.com/table.php?distribution=ubuntu)
Specifically Ubuntu 8.10 "intrepid" would fit if another distro absolutely has to be the solution.


This is a site that specificly talks about the issues you are having and a given work around
[updating python on rhelc entos](http://blog.boxedice.com/2010/01/19/updating-python-on-rhelcentos/)


This site keeps a list of updates for rhel
[iuscommunity](http://iuscommunity.org/)